# Find innodb undo size

Tags: mysql, innodb, undo

I'm using MySQL 5.5.33 on RHEL. I have innodb_file_per_table enabled but in the ibdata1 is rather large. I've hypothesised that it's from me running a consistent backup meaning the UNDO   space has grown. Is there anyway to confirm this? I'm not finding anything in information_schema that could lead me to this - ideally I'd like a break down of the sizes in ibdata1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

all of My colleagues and My friends and me had tried how to figure out this. But we couldn't find anything about it. The only thing I know (you know) is mysqldump and delete all innodb files & restore.

[MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/08/20/why-is-the-ibdata1-file-continuously-growing-in-mysql/) gives us important 2 stories.

**1. check what is being stored in the ibdata1**

> Unfortunately MySQL doesn’t provide information of what is being stored on that ibdata1 shared tablespace but there are two tools that will be very helpful. First a modified version of innochecksum made by Mark Callaghan and published in this bug report.

**2. Is there any way to recover the used space?**

> No, it is not possible at least in an easy and fast way. InnoDB tablespaces never shrink… see the following 10-year old bug report recently updated by James Day (thanks):

OP has solved his question using `the modified innochecksum script`. excerpted from his comment.

> I ended up using the modified innochecksum script and it worked on the live ibdata1 file. Turns out I was right, mostly UNDO with a large portion of insert buffers too

Comment: I don't need to shrink it, I'm just curious as to what is taking up the space. The only think I can find is the number of rollback segments, just not the size of each extent.

Comment: @dwjv not sure you already have read this. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/08/20/why-is-the-ibdata1-file-continuously-growing-in-mysql/ there mentioned * " Unfortunately MySQL doesn’t provide information of what is being stored on that ibdata1 shared tablespace but there are two tools that will be very helpful"*

Comment: I ended up using the modified innochecksum script and it worked on the live ibdata1 file. Turns out I was right, mostly UNDO with a large portion of insert buffers too.